# Regex engine does not have a global filter and not accepting flag

Tags: regex, modifier

I can check "global" on this site that I use for testing. I took off global and tried adding /g to my regex and it doesn't work. I am trying to add it manually because in the live environment the regex engine doesn't have a global filter.

I have tried /g and the start and end of regex and turning off the automatic filter

```
(?=(Booked|Cancelled|Reschedule))(?<status>\1)|(?<acct>M\d{9})|(? 
=Procedure Date:\s*(?<m>\d{2})\/(?<d>\d{2})\/(?<y>\d{2}))
```

if I remove the modifier from the website or try to add it myself, it ignores the matches.here is a de o

https://regex101.com/r/igjCuo/48

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: `g` flag is not part of the regex engine, it can only be used in the regex literal notation in some languages, not all. What is your environment?

Comment: PCRE (PHP) I am using it on Summit Scheduler which has is ran off PHP.

Comment: Hello, what I thought was a global issue, because (1/4) of the matches were being returned. It seems like it is being captured but not displayed. I am not sure why                                                      
                                                            
           https://regex101.com/r/igjCuo/53

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but in PHP you can make use of `preg_match_all`. It even works with newlines, so you don't have to replace them with `{newline}`.

Assuming the regex is complete:

```
<?php
$file = $argv[1];
$rgx="/(?=(Booked|Cancelled|Reschedule))(?<status>\1)|(?<acct>M\d{9})|(?=Procedure Date:\s*(?<m>\d{2})\/(?<d>\d{2})\/(?<y>\d{2}))/";
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
$data = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
preg_match_all($rgx, $data, $array);
var_dump($array);
```

I've saved the code as `test.php` and validated it as follows.

```
$ php test.php txt_newline.txt > test.a
$ php test.php txt_no_newline.txt > test.b
$ md5sum test.a test.b 
5880b9977830066f5b8bd0bea41ebb0f  test.a
5880b9977830066f5b8bd0bea41ebb0f  test.b
```

I hope it helps. [Here's](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) the full manual for `preg_match_all`.

Comment: @imlight which output do you expect? How much notices(?) does one file/string/whatever hold? If you describe your problem in more details, I will be able to help you.